# Specify the ABI of a function

Tags: ats

Is there a way to specify the ABI of a function directly in ATS?
For instance, I want to do this:

```
%{^
typedef uint64_t __attribute__((ms_abi)) (*function)(uint16_t*);
%}
```

but in ATS instead of C.

**Edit:**
Here's my original problem:

```
%{^
struct SimpleTextOutputInterface;

typedef uint64_t __attribute__((ms_abi)) (*EfiTextString)(struct SimpleTextOutputInterface*, uint16_t*);
%}

typedef EfiTextString = $extype"EfiTextString"

vtypedef SimpleTextOutputInterface =
   @{ reset = EfiTextReset
    , output_string = [l:addr] (EfiTextString@l | ptr l)
    }
```

and I want to call `output_string` with the `ms_abi`. I can do it in C, but I don't know if it is possible to do without C.

Comment: I want to stress that ATS is not meant to replace C; it is supposed to be used together with C (that is, so-called ATS and C co-programming). If you show me how the type 'function' is supposed to be used in C, then I may be able to suggest something.

Comment: @HongweiXi: I edited the question to show my original problem. Is there a way to call a function with a different ABI in ATS?

Comment: I see the issue now. I would define EfiTextString_app to apply EfiTextString to two arguments and then implement EfiTextString_app as a macro in C.